# Installing and USB Boot problems

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I initially tried running Ubuntu off of a USB flash drive, but the files got deleted. Now when I boot my laptop it shows both Windows 7 and Ubuntu operating systems, but the Ubuntu system says it's missing a file and can't run it.

After the files were lost I downloaded Ubuntu on a CD and installed it on my hard drive following the instructions on the installation menu, but the same error message shows up whenever I try to run Ubuntu. It says I'm missing some files, as if it were still trying to run it from a USB.

How can I remove the nonfunctional Ubuntu from my boot menu?

Comment: Please be more clear. Which files got deleted? You say you tried running Ubuntu from a flash drive. Just running of a flash drive won't put anything on your hard drive. Did you try to install as well? When using the CD are you trying to Install or "Try Ubuntu?"

Comment: You may have to [repair GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Go inside Ubuntu and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update the menus.
If not then kindly reinstall the OS on the exact same location.
When reinstalling, do not repartition, do not select format, select same / and /home partitions as before.

OR

try using the `ubuntu recovery mode`.

One of the 3 should work for you.
Thank you.